# List of events around a coordinate during a period of time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, semantic-web

As above.

I've tried the FQL query

```
SELECT eid FROM event WHERE 
   (start_time > 2011-08-19T03:00:00+0000) AND (end_time < 2011-08-19T08:00:00+0000) AND
   ((venue.latitude + 0.005 > 23.7490375) OR (venue.latitude - 0.005 < 23.7490375)) AND
   ((venue.longitude + 0.005 > 90.39463031) OR (venue.longitude - 0.005 < 90.39463031)))
```

The result I got was

> Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

Is there a way to get this information using either facebook or some other database service?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to search with the level of detail you are looking for.

Within FQL, the event table needs an index, you can try using `AND CONTAINS('a')` to select all events that contain the character a. It's a very brute force approach.